# JavaScript - How to extract data from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular

Something like Jsoup in Java, but for JavaScript. I want to extract data from an unknown website and highlight important features to the user. To start with, I need to extract first. I need to work strictly on JavaScript. jQuery has some potential but requires a lot of hard work. Any good, stable JS library will be appreciated.
 I want to create a DOM tree structure from that unknown page so that I can get other elements by searching for id tags.

Comment: `jQuery has some potential but requires lot of hard work`:- in comparison to pure java-script your sentence is wrong.

Comment: I want to create a DOM tree structure from that unknown page so that I can get other elements by searching for id tags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)? It provides a similar API to jQuery but is designed to run in Node.js.